# Align a set of elements that are not next to each other in the HTML

Tags: jquery, css, alignment, css-tables

I am creating a comparison table where the columns are built as below:

```
<div id = "wrapper">

<div id = "col1">
<div class = "row1">
 text
 lots more text
 and more text
</div>
<div class = "row2">
 text
</div>
<div class = "row3">
 text
</div>
</div>

<div id = "col2">
<div class = "row1">
  text
</div>
<div class = "row2">
  a  
  lot
  of

  text
</div>
<div class = "row3">
  text
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Col1 and col2 are then displayed as an `inline-block` so they visually sit next to each other on the page.

The problem is that the contents of each row may vary. Without setting a min-height of each row, how could i make sure that each row visually lines up with its corresponding row from the other column?

I can't think of any way to achieve this in CSS alone. I'm wondering if there's some sneaky jQuery way of achieving this?

EDIT: I Can't change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, in the end i found the answer here

[jQuery Set Height of Element to Highest in the group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079803/jquery-set-height-of-element-to-highest-in-the-group)

Im now looploopign through the elements in question like so

```
// Set options
var height = 0;
var element_wrap = ".compare-items-wrapper";
var element_search = ".financial_annual_fees";

// Search through the elements set and see which is the highest.
jQuery(element_wrap).each(function () {
    jQuery(this).find(element_search).each(function () {
        if (height < jQuery(this).height()) height = jQuery(this).height();
    });

    //alert("Block Height: " +height);

    // Set the height for the element wrap.
    jQuery(element_search).css("height", (height+10) + "px");

    // Unset height
    height = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to make the outer divs rows, and the inner divs columns. Then when the height changes, the entire row will increase in height. Then you can give percent or static widths for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the structure of the html so that it is a number of rows that each contain two columns, then you can do this with CSS using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell`.

The HTML would need to be like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="row1" class="row">
        <div class="column">
          text lots more text and more text
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          text lots more text and more text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="row">
        <div class="column">
            text lots more text and more text
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            text lots more text and more text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row3" class="row">
        <div class="column">
            text lots more text and more text
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

.row .column {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's a demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9Fj0y15FrjDJ7CQ00hzk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but should have mentioned i cant change the HTML